# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (), youTube API with Netlify

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api, netlify

im doing a React Youtube clone with te youtube API, and its working fine in a local server, but when I host the project with Netlify I have this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at e.exports (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onreadystatechange (xhr.js:61)
```

I also tried to host with Firebase, and there is no error but the data never load..

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:
check the Authorization Guide for how to consume the Youtube API. It may be allowed for localhost usage but requires you to register a web application with credentials.

[Authorization Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps)